# SQL : how do you create a trigger in a SQL database to update a last modified date column

Tags: sql, triggers

I need to update a database column with a date stamp when another column has been modified.

E.g when database spec table schematics column `Partstatusid` is changed, stamp needs to be updated.

I have read I need to create a trigger, but as my skill set is solely SQL report writing and query based, I am not 100% of the code...

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi, please tell us first which database system you use.

Comment: The syntax for database triggers depends highly on the concrete database product you use. Are we talking about oracle, postgresql, sql server, mysql or something else? You can do this easily by setting a matching tag on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided a DBMS I will provide two options, one for `MS SQL Server` and one for `Oracle`. If you need something other than that, please specify what DBMS you are using.

For MS SQL Server:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tiu_data_table
ON dbo.data_table
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(Partstatusid)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.data_table
        SET last_updated = GETDATE()
        WHERE id_col IN (SELECT id_col FROM Inserted)
    END
END
```

For Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tiu_data_table
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "schema_name".data_table FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    IF UPDATING('Partstatusid') THEN
        :NEW.last_updated := SYSDATE;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: For MS SQL server, I would add condition to compare new and old `Partstatusid` - OP most likely needs to watch only value changes, not overwrites with same value. For Oracle I have no idea, is that needed or not.

Comment: I added that already with the `UPDATE()` for SQL Server and the `UPDATING()` for Oracle.

Comment: `update(...)` is always true if field is updated - even with same value.